# Can't build UserControls under x64

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, build, 64-bit

I am trying to troubleshoot a VB.NET project that contains UserControls (actually, several of them that are displaying the same issues). I am trying to get them to build under x64, but it is impossible. In x86 or AnyCPU, the UserControl builds and shows up in the Toolbox, so I can add or modify it in the forms that require it. In x64, the controls disappear from the Toolbox, I get warnings during build (the current project builds though), I can't see any of the forms - I get errors (please see below) - and projects that require the project with the form as an import will not build.
When I was studying what these UserControls are so that I can maybe rebuild them from scratch, I downloaded code from a book - great learning tool, but I get the same errors:

```
Could not find type 'Chap15SampleCode.ListSelector'.  Please make sure that the assembly that contains this type is referenced.  If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU.

The variable 'ListSelector1' is either undeclared or was never assigned.
```

I also get warnings, not sure what to do about them:

```
Possible problem detected while building assembly 'Chap15SampleCode': Referenced assembly 'mscorlib.dll' targets a different processor
Possible problem detected while building assembly 'Chap15SampleCode': Referenced assembly 'System.Data.dll' targets a different processor
```

I checked and found System.Data as a Reference is in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework... (if I change the target framework to 4.0 the Reference is in c:\ProgramFiles(x86)... that was what my projects had ... and I tried to change it because of the x86, I couldn't, I had a few others in ProgramFiles(x86) and I thought that may be the problem ?)
Reinstalled VS2010, reinstalled Windows - did the same before btw - but I do have a clean system so I can't blame it. 
If I can get this simple project to work, I hope the real projects will be easy - Please help me figure out what this is about. Thank you.

Comment: ListSelector1 is the UserControl that is generated by the form designer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have changed the Platform target setting in the project to x64.  This is not appropriate for any project that produces a DLL.  The actual bitness of a process that uses your DLL is determined by the EXE that starts the process.  Or the host in which your DLL runs, the case for Visual Studio which is a 32-bit process.  There is nothing a DLL can do to force the bitness, it can only refuse to get loaded.  Which is what you see happening.

Change the setting back to AnyCPU so that your UserControl will work correctly in any process, regardless of its bitness.  Including the VS designer.  Project + Properties, Build tab.  For VB.NET it is located in the Compile tab, Advanced Compile Options button.

Comment: Is there a similar setting for c# projects ?

Comment: I documented that, Build tab.

Comment: On Build -> Platform I put AnyCPU but it didn't make the same difference.

Comment: Hard to guess, make sure you rebuild.  And if you added the control to the toolbox by hand then make sure you remove it by hand as well.  Choose Items context menu item.

Comment: Oddly enough, after removing and re-adding the errant code, cleaning and rebuilding before and after - everything works. Party time !